# Change text color of kivy ListView ListItemButton

Tags: python, listview, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to change the color of the text displayed on each of my buttons in a python kivy ListView object.

My kivy code looks as follows (nothing much in my python code):

```
#:kivy 1.9.1
#:import BoxLayout kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import ListView kivy.uix.listview
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton

<ListItemButton>:
    selected_color: 200, 200, 200, 1  
    deselected_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

BoxLayout:
    ListView:
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(
            data=['Home', 'Work', 'Other', 'Custom'],
            cls=ListItemButton, 
            selection_mode='multiple', 
            allow_empty_selection=True,
            )

        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (100, 44)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
```

I'm able to successfully change the color of the button when it's selected/deselected (using `<ListItemButton>`), but I can't seem to find any clear explanation as to how to change the color of the text itself.

`Markup: True` would be useful, but I also can't get that to work.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that the default button as an API for changing the text color. You can set the text to `""` and add a Label over the button with the same positioning and the label you want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/LcLj02Qd2PY

```
<ListItemButton>:
    selected_color: 200, 200, 200, 1  
    deselected_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
```